# How to pipe from Command to File?

Tags: rust

Let's say I have:

```
fn pipe(cmd: &mut std::process::Command, file: &mut File) {
}
```

I want to somehow pipe from `cmd.stdout` to `file` without storing everything into an intermediary buffer. I'm trying stuff out with `BufReader` but I feel like I'm missing something.

Comment: So I really need to use unsafe and a 3rd party crate to achieve this?

Comment: The third party crate is for creating the stdin pipe. Here you just want the redirection. You do need unsafe unless you update the signature to `file: File`: there's an `impl From<File> for Stdio` so you can just `.stdout(file)`, however that requires an owned file. If you don't own the file you have to go through raw FDs, and that's unsafe.